# Headphones don't work in Xenial 16.04

Tags: 16.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, alienware

I was running lubuntu Xenial but was unable to get the headphones working after trying all of the different possible fixes I could find. I have finally given up on trying to fix it myself and have come to you all for help (by actually asking a question).

The sound works for the integrated laptop speakers, however the 3.5mm audio jack does not seem to be recognized by the OS. Additionally, there is no 'headphone' option in the sound settings, nor in alsamixer, nor in any other sound gui or command line interface I can find.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled alsa and pulseaudio to no avail and finally tried to just do a fresh install of ubuntu xenial (which I am now talking from) but this did not solve the problem.

Please assist if you can. Thanks!

alsa-utils.sh output: http://pastebin.com/raw/86myHZ4x

```
    $USER:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Headphones are now recognized if I go into `alsamixer` and enable HP/Speaker Auto Detect and run `sudo alsa force-reload`

Possibly one step closer... I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
hdajackretask
```

Which allowed me to override the 'Orange Headphone, Front side' pin 0x10 with 'Headphone' which makes it so that ubuntu recognizes when the headphones are plugged into the correct headphones port. Still no sound coming into them, but at least it knows when it's plugged in.

Also have to run `ps -ef | grep pulseaudio` run `kill <pulseaudio-pid> && sudo alsa force-reload` to get the `snd-hda-intel` module to reload but doing so kills the headphone recognition again.

Comment: Also, I'm terribly sorry for misspelling Xenial in the title. Fat fingers

Comment: Did you try [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519955&p=9558775#post9558775)?

Comment: I tried that, one step closer I think. I modified that line then did 'sudo alsa force-reload' went into alsamixer and turned on 'HP Auto-detect' and now the headphones are showing in pavucontrol. However, there's still no sound coming from the headphones. I also tried using different headphones but there still isn't any sound coming out.

Comment: Did you reboot after changing the modprobe.d file?

Comment: Yes, I've rebooted a couple of times now. It also seems that the problem may be with Alienware's choice of sound card... the creative sound blaster doesn't seem to have a whole lot of support for linux. That said, I do finally see headphones (plugged in) in pavucontrol. Gonna do another reboot just to see if something magically fixes itself. Also, there is a headphone port and a microphone port on the alienware and the headphones plugged in port only shows up when I plug into the microphone port. Not sure if maybe that has something to do with it... Trying to figure out how to swap them out.

Comment: Also, when I turn on the HP auto detect setting is the only time headphones appear when I plug in to the microphone jack. If I don't type that in and do a 'sudo alsa force-reload' then the headphones don't appear in pavu control. Doing so, though, removes the analog sound option from the gnome sound settings.

Answer (score 0):

I just install Ubuntu 16.04 right now and my headphones were *enjoying the silence*.
After 2 minutes of hardcore googleing I found [this link](http://www.codemarvels.com/2016/02/installing-ubuntu-on-alienware-17-r2/).

The relevant information its shown below:

Fix issue with headphones not working: –

```
Open Terminal
alsamixer
Press F6
Select “HDA Intel PCH” card
Press right arrow till the Item shown is “HP/Speaker Auto Detect”
Press M to set it on.
Connect headphones and verify if it works.
```

Follow step by step the instructions and swept up with music!

Comment: I think the issue is that the alienware 17 r3 drivers are not supported yet by alsa/pulseaudio. I bought a usb sound card as a workaround which works well enough.